# Comment signaler les contre-exemples et les exemples discutables ? How should counterexamples and debatable examples be marked?

Tags: discussion

Il m’arrive parfois, lorsque je réponds à une question, de donner en plus d’exemples des contre-exemples : des phrases incorrectes pour signaler les erreurs à éviter ou pour faciliter la compréhension du propos.

Il m’arrive également de donner des exemples douteux : des exemples grammaticalement corrects mais pas utilisés, des constructions archaïques et d’autres encore.

Mais hélas, le lecteur tant que l’auteur peuvent faire des contresens, particulièrement sur un site fréquenté par des locuteurs de différentes langues. Et il serait vraiment dommageable qu’un contre-exemple soit interprété comme une phrase correcte.

Comment alors signaler simplement et de façon la plus directement compréhensible possible ce qui est un contre-exemple et ce qui est un exemple douteux ?

J’ai tendance à tirer un trait sur les contre-exemples. Certes cela nuit à la lisibilité, mais peut-être est-ce un moindre mal quand la phrase est incorrecte de toute manière.

> **Exemple :** <strike>Ce phrase est erroné.</strike>

En matière d’exemple douteux, je ne les signale pas pour le moment. Sur papier, j’aurais tendance à les souligner en zigzag, mais outre le problème de la réalisation je crains que ça ne nuise à la lisibilité de la ligne *suivante*.

Que suggéreriez-vous ?

---

Sometimes, when I answer a question, I give not only examples, but also couter-examples: erroneous sentences used to point out typical errors to avoid or to make its meaning clearer.

Some other times, I use dubious examples: grammatically correct examples which are not in usage, archaic constructs, etc.

Unfortunately, the reader can misinterpret the author meaning or the author themselves can mistranslate their idea when writing. This is especially likely on a website whose visitors speaks various languages.

How would you then mark counter-examples and dubious examples so that it is both easy and readily comprehensible?

I usually strike the counter-examples. It makes them harder to read, but I doubt it matters much given that they are already wrong in the first place.

> **Example:** <strike>This sentence is errorous.</strike>

As for dubious examples, I don’t highlight them yet. On By hand, I would probably to underline them with a wave, but I have no idea how this could be implemented and I’m afraid it could make the *next* line harder to read.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 9):

Il est d'usage dans les textes sur la langue d'indiquer une phrase incorrecte en la précédant d'un astérisque.

> *Cette phrase est incorrecte.

Cependant, cet usage n'est pas universellement connu, et l'astérisque n'est pas très visible. Je recommande donc de le combiner avec le barré.

> *<s>Cette phrase est incorrecte.</s>

```
\*<s>Cette phrase est incorrecte.</s>
```

La barre oblique inverse n'est pas nécessaire ici, mais elle l'est quelquefois pour éviter que l'astérisque ne soit interprété comme une demande de mise en forme.

Je pense que pour une phrase qui est correcte mais douteuse, une remarque suffit (« traduction mot-à-mot », « construction grammaticalement correcte mais non idiomatique », ...).

---

There is a convention in texts about language to mark an incorrect clause with a leading asterisk.

> *This sentence is errorous.

However this is not universally known, and the asterisk is easy to miss, so I recommend combining it with overstrike.

> *<s>This sentence is errorous.</s>

```
\*<s>This sentence is errorous.</s>
```

The backslash isn't necessary here, but sometimes it is required so that the asterisk isn't interpreted as a formatting command.

For a sentence which is dubious but not incorrect, I think a remark is enough (“word-for-word translation”, “grammatically correct but non-idiomatic”, …).

Comment: Ou simplement barré, sans l'astérisque.